# Best Size for Mobile Viewport ( Scaling Down )

Tags: mobile

I'm building a website that I really need to be visible on mobile devices, so I'm building that at a standard `320px`. However this is a little bit too narrow in my opinion. I upped the width to `440px` and found that it showed up pretty well on my Galaxy S4 using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=440, maximum-scale=1">`, meaning that it has been shrunk down slightly to show up on the screen.

Is there an "official" Maximum width that you should be using on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "official" maximum width for mobile devices. According to the below source, 480px would be the recommended maximum.

You might want to scale down your viewports incrementally from there if viewing your website on a mobile phone is important to you such as 480px and another viewport for 320px.

Src: http://www.zingdesign.com/responsive-website-design-cheatsheet1/

Src: http://mydevice.io/devices/ or http://viewportsizes.com/ (Common smartphone values)

Comment: Thanks Craig. To be honest I'm wanting to build a site that is "One size fits all", so the same site will show up on a mobile and Desktop. A 320 width is great for what I'm doing, but feel that video playback will be a bit disappointing on such a small scale.